# How do I add multiple jlabels to a button?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, user-interface, button

So what I tried to do is create multiple JLabels, each corresponding to different data (name, attck_value, health_power, etc.), and add them separately to the already created button. However, I ended up getting the button with all the data overlapping one another. So what should I do? How do I add multiple JLabels without them getting overlapped?

Comment: Why are you adding multiple labels to a single button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess here, but did you know you can add `html` to a `JButton` to create multiple line names.  And you can change the text at any time while the GUI is in operation so the JButton can change its meaning.

```
JButton b = new JButton("<html>this<br>is<br>a<br><test></html>");
```

[image]